# Remove file Synchronously can't find file

Tags: node.js

I have this function that make a directory have same files as the other one, so one directory is the source and the other is the one that should look like it so it removes files found in the second one that doesn't exist in the src. Anyway the thing is in the function below if I replaced `fs.rmdirSync`with `fs.rmdir` it works but if I don't it returns the error shown below.

```
function (srcDir, similarDir){

        srcDir = path.resolve(process.cwd(),srcDir);
        similarDir = path.resolve(process.cwd(),similarDir);
        var info = {deletedFiles : 0, deletedDir : 0};
        dive(similarDir,function(err, file){
            if(err){
                console.log(err.toString())
            }
            else
            {
                var baseFile = path.basename(file,'.css');
                var srcFileDir = path.dirname(file).replace(similarDir,srcDir)
                var srcFilePath = path.resolve(srcFileDir , baseFile);

                if(!fs.existsSync(srcFilePath)){
                    console.log("before");
                    try {
                        fs.rmdirSync(file)
                    }
                    catch(error){
                        console.log(error)
                    }
                    console.log("after");
                    info.deletedFiles++;
                }

            }
        })
```

This is the error that occurs when I use `fs.rmdirsync` although the file does exist and If i changed it to `fs.rmdir` it works ( on windows os )

```
{ [Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'D:\angularjs\build\css\components\test\test\test.css']
  errno: 34,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'D:\\angularjs\\build\\css\\components\\test\\test\\test.css',
  syscall: 'rmdir' }
```

Comment: I just encountered the same issue, were you ever able to resolve this?

Answer (score -1):

Try upgrading to [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fs-extra), fs.removeSync() works without issue.